# How to send values of input elements ( text / select / radio ) to node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I receive the values of the radio buttons and a select list and put it on the file name?

This is the function that will be using the values :

```js
router.get('/import', function(req, res, next) {
  var csvStream = fastCsv()
    .on('data', function(data) {
      var report = new csvUploads({
        jirakey: data[0],
        status: data[1],
        priority: data[2],
        validity: data[3],
        type: data[4],
        month: data[5],
        defectCategory: data[6],
        defectSubCategory: data[7]
      });

      report.save(function(error) {
        console.log(report);
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }
      });
    }).on('end', function() {});
  const request = req.body;
  let month = req.month;
  let team = req.team;
  const filename = month + ' - ' + team + '.csv';
  console.log(res.send(filename));
  const csvFilePath = "./uploads/" + filename;
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath);
  stream.pipe(csvStream);
  res.json({
    success: 'Data imported successfully',
    status: 200
  });
});
```

Currently this is what I have tried, it returns `undefined` in both the radio button and select list value

Comment: We cant help you unless you give more info.
That is not really going to work this way...

Comment: what are the needed information? I tried getting the value through the req.body and it throws undefined

Comment: [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ...nevertheless, I have answered with a working concept that sounds like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you simply serve the view (importer.html) and use it as as a client for your server (using POST), that way you may interact with the server and display the changes/retrieved data back in the client.

You will be needing :

1. `GET` route for displaying the "client".
2. `POST` route for using the "client submitted data and crafting an
   adecuate response".
3. Client logic for doing something when the server replies.

Hope this proof-of-concept (working example) will help you understand better :

> **SERVER CODE**

```
const express = require('express'); global.app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
/* SETUP SERVER CONFIG OPTIONS */
const CONF = {
  "htmlDir":__dirname+"/",
  "port":3000
}
//----------------------------------------------------------
//.: Server StratUp : Setup Event Handling :.
function InitializeServer(){
 console.log("[~] starting ...")
 //:[EXPRESS]:MiddleWare
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
 app.use(bodyParser.json())
 //:[EXPRESS]:Router (GET Requests)
 app.get("/",RenderImport)
 //:[EXPRESS]:Router (POST Requests)
 app.post("/import",ImportRequest)
 //:[EXPRESS]:Start
 app.listen(CONF.port,onSuccessfullStartup)
}
/*   Callback example for express successfully listening  */
const onSuccessfullStartup=()=>{
 console.log("[i] ready & listening","\n http://localhost:"+CONF.port+"/")
}
//----------------------------------------------------------
/*                ROUTER EVENT FUNCTIONS :                */
const RenderImport=(req,res)=>{res.sendFile(CONF.htmlDir+"importer.html")}
const ImportRequest=(req,res)=>{
  console.log("[POST] /import")
  console.log(req.body)
 if(req.body.stringExample&&req.body.selectExample&&req.body.radioExample){
   console.log(" > valid POSTData")
   var doSomethingNow={"status":"OK","data":[1,2,3,4,5]}
   res.json(doSomethingNow)
 }else{
   console.log(" > invalid POSTData")
   res.json({"status":"ERROR"})
 }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------
InitializeServer()  // We can now start the server
```

> **CLIENT CODE (importer.html)**

```
<html><head><title>INDEX</title></head><body>
 <center>
  <h1>SEND DATA TO SERVER</h1>
  <form name="theForm">
   <!-- String Example -->
   <input name="stringExample" type="text"></input>
   <!-- Select Example -->
   <select name="selectExample">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
   <select>
   <!-- Radio Example -->
   <input type="radio" name="radioExample" value="a" checked> One
   <input type="radio" name="radioExample" value="b" > Other
   <input type="radio" name="radioExample" value="c" > Another
  </form>
  <button onclick="SEND()">SEND</button>
 </center>
 <script>
 function SEND(){
   var newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
   newXHR.addEventListener("load",RequestDone);
   newXHR.open("POST","/import");
   newXHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
   //Fetch Form Data
   var form = document.theForm;
   var inputx = form.elements["stringExample"];
   var select = form.elements["selectExample"];
   var radios = form.elements["radioExample"];
   //Data for POST
   var JSONObj = {}
   JSONObj.stringExample = inputx.value
   JSONObj.selectExample = select.value
   JSONObj.radioExample = radios.value
   console.log(JSONObj);
   //Format Data for POST
   var POSTData = JSON.stringify(JSONObj);
   newXHR.send(POSTData);
 }
 function RequestDone(req){
   var res = JSON.parse(req.target.response); console.log(res)
   if(res.status=="OK"){alert("Succesfully Sent & Retrieved Data :\n"+res.data.toString())}
   else if(res.status=="ERROR"){alert("The server received unexpected data or is missing important parameters")}
   else{alert("Unexcpected Error!")}
 }
 </script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
 const request = req.body;
 let month = req.month;
 let team = req.team;
```

try

```
 const request = req.body;
 let month = request.month;
 let team = request.team;
```