# Display MySQL data into HTML div - Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am struggling to output the data from MySQL into my HTML page. I need suggestions on how I can extract data from MySQL and display it on my HTML page. As you can see below, the server code connects to the HTML page and MySQL, but I just need to input the MySQL data into the HTML div.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Data from MySQL</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="output_message"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mywebsite"
});

connection.connect();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM chat", function(err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(result[0].Message));
    });
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Connected to port 3000');
});
```

Comment: You should read up on how to do basic templating in a node application. The docs are very clearL https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Dependind on your needs :

#### · Server Renders Data :

You will be needing a `view engine` such as `hbs`

([as Robert Moskal stated in a comment to your question, it is very clearly explained](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html))

---

#### · Client Renders Data :

You will need to :

**1]** extract the db query from the `app.get("/")` and make it part of the
    logic in `app.post("/")`

```
app.get("/",(req, res)=>{res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html")})

app.post('/',(req, res)=>{
 connection.query("SELECT * FROM chat",(err, result)=>{
  if(err){console.log(err); res.json({"error":true}) }
  else{ console.log(result); res.json(result) }
 })
})
```

**2]** make a POST request from your client to the new router's post path.

**3]** receive the response at the client and manipulate the DOM to display the data.

[Here you can find an example of sending a post request and receiving the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642976/how-to-send-values-of-input-elements-text-select-radio-to-node-js-server/50174869#50174869)